# How to read binary secrets from GCP Secret Manager

Tags: node.js, ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I am trying to store pfx certificates on GCP secret manager. My node app works fine when reading the certificate files from local filesystem via fs.readFileSync however when i fetch the certificate via gcp secret manager client library, i am getting a **mac verification error**during the node http request (passphrase is also correct and stored  on gcp secret manager, checked it with openssl).

my request is node/https with following options,

```
const options = {
            host: url.host,
            path: url.path,
            method: "POST",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            pfx: IdCert,
            ca: CaCert,
            passphrase: CertPass,
            rejectUnauthorized: true,
        };
```

And the way i am accessing the the certificate is via getSecretData below:

```
const {SecretManagerServiceClient} = require('@google-cloud/secret-manager');
const asyncConfig = require('config/async').asyncConfig;
const client = new SecretManagerServiceClient();

const getSecretData = ( projectId, name )=>{
    const close = async ()=>{
      const [version] = await client.accessSecretVersion({
        name: `projects/${projectId}/secrets/${name}/versions/latest`,
      });
  
      return  version.payload.data;    
    }
return close;
}
```

PS: using node-config to store certificates inside the instance and access them via

```
const config = require("config"); // node-config package
const IdCert = config.get('IdCert')
```

Comment: Have you tried calling “toString()” on the payload data? I believe it comes back as a buffer.

Comment: yes tried that, but after a further check, the buffer uploaded to gcp is 30 80 02 01 03 .. (read from gcp console), and the buffer read via node is 30 82 0b 09 02 .. So the issue might be somewhere around where you are pointing

Comment: Could also be encoding then...

Answer (score 0):

The secrets are stored in base64 format. You need to decode your data before using them.